# Paypal Payments Advanced/Pro Layout C with Recurring Payments?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I have a Paypal pro account.  Following the videos below from paypal explain what I'm trying to do, ***except*** that it does not explain how to create recurring billing profile through this method.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qyiv3ndRcZI

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Z5v-ha0YII

I understand through the API how to manually create a recurring billing profile through the Direct Payment API (Recurring), but this only works for users that don't want to go through paypal (even though technically it is).  For the people that choose to pay through paypal, I believe it brings them to express checkout.  How do I create an iframe on my page like the layout C examples in those videos except for recurring billing instead of a 1 time payment?

I've read in some documentation somewhere about a BAID (Buyers Agreement ID) that might be necessary but I don't know how I would integrate it in the example code they give in those videos.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iframe solution you're referring to is called Payments Advanced.  To my knowledge recurring billing is not yet included with Advanced.

The full PayPal Pro would give you access to create profiles with cards directly like you mentioned, or if you want to let them do it with payPal you would send them through the [Express Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) flow, and that's where you would be creating the billing agreement and the profile accordingly.

Specifically, you'll call [SetExpressCheckout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/) to obtain a token, and this is the request you need to make sure to include the billing agreement parameters with.

[GetExpressCheckoutDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) would then allow you to obtain buyer info after they've signed in and agreed to continue.

Then for recurring payments you'd finish it all off with [CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/).

If you're doing all of this with PHP I'd recommend taking a look at my [class library for PayPal](http://www.angelleye.com/product/php-class-library-paypal/).  It'll make these API calls very simple for you.

Comment: That is a really nice class you got there.  I'm going to give it a try for creating the express checkout.  Can you pass custom variables through to Paypal? Reason I ask is because I require customers to pay with their credit card or Paypal during the account creation process.  If payment fails the account will not be created, if it succeeds, I still need to make the account.  Not sure the best way to go about this, because if it goes to Paypal their account info is kind of in limbo.  I suppose I could put it in local storage... not sure that is the best way.

Comment: I like to save orders as pending prior to sending people over to PayPal.  That way I can include my local invoice ID in the Invoice parameter of the API requests, and then that'll be available to pull data back out of my database or update the existing record when the order is completed.  For the actual post-payment processing (updating your db, sending email notifications, etc.) I'd recommending using IPN.

Comment: For IPN you might want to take a look at my [IPN template](http://www.angelleye.com/product/paypal-instant-payment-notification-ipn-php-template/).  I developed it a long time ago, so it's a little rudimentary, but it's fully functional and still very useful.